# Where does Benatar defend in 'Better Never to Have Been' that (though logically possible) absence of pleasure can't be bad?

Tags: antinatalism

Source: Benatar, David. [*Better Never to Have Been*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199549265) (2008 1 edn). pp. 30 Bottom - 31 Top.

> [...] it strikes me as true that
>
> > (3) the absence of pain is good, even if that good is not enjoyed
> >     by anyone,
> >     whereas
> >     (4) the absence of pleasure is not bad unless there is somebody
> >     for whom this absence is a deprivation.
>
> Now it might be asked how the absence of pain could be good if
>   that good is not enjoyed by anybody. Absent pain, it might be said,
>   cannot be good *for* anybody, if nobody exists for whom it can be
>   good. This, however, is to dismiss (3) too quickly.
>
> The judgement made in (3) is made *with reference to the (potential)
>   interests of a person* who either does or does not exist. To this it
>
> might be objected that because (3) is part of the scenario under
>   which this person never exists, (3) cannot say anything about an
>   existing person. This objection would be mistaken because (3) can
>   say something about a counterfactual case in which a person who
>   does actually exist never did exist. Of the pain of an existing person,
>   () says that the absence of this pain would have been good even if
>   this could only have been achieved by the absence of the person
>   who now suffers it. In other words, judged in terms of the interests
>   of a person who now exists, the absence of the pain would have
>   been good even though this person would then not have existed.
>   Consider next what (3) says of the absent pain of one who never
>   exists—of pain, the absence of which is ensured by not making
>   a potential person actual. Claim (3) says that this absence is good
>   when judged in terms of the interests of the person who would
>   otherwise have existed. We may not know who that person would
>   have been, but we can still say that whoever that person would
>   have been, the avoidance of his or her pains is good when judged
>   in terms of his or her potential interests. If there is any (obviously
>   loose) sense in which the absent pain is good for the person who
>   could have existed but does not exist, this is it. Clearly (3) does not
>   entail the absurd literal claim that there is some actual person for
>   whom the absent pain is good.<sup>²³</sup>
>
> <sup>²³</sup> One *could* (logically) make symmetrical claims about the absence of
>   pleasure—that, when judged in terms of the (potential) interests of a person
>   who does or does not exist, this absence of pleasure is bad. However, (4) suggests
>   that this symmetrical claim, although logically possible, is actually false. **I shall defend
>   (4) later [emboldening mine].** For now my aim has been only to show that (3) is not incoherent.

On what page does Benatar defend (4)?

Comment: Since you seem to have electronic version of the book this should be answerable with a text search.

Comment: @Conifold I'm using the print version. It isn't though? I read this book twice, and after this page, he doesn't explicitly where.